# Updating Operating System to play Diablo 3

Tags: macbook-pro, games

My girlfriend has a MacBook Air 2012 and we were thinking of playing Diablo 3 together. When she tried to install Diablo 3, she got an error saying that her operating system is outdated. She tried to update her operating system but received an error that she cannot update her OS. I have several questions:

1. Does Apple impose an operating system cap because her Mac is too old?
2. Is it advisable to upgrade her operating system to the lastest version, or would it be too much of a strain on her system resource?

Macbook Air 2012: Spec
https://support.apple.com/kb/sp670?locale=en_US

- i5 - 1.8Ghz
- HD Graphics 4000
- 4GB RAM
- 128GB SSD

Comment: The 2012 Macbook Air is eligible for macOS 10.12 Sierra, which is currently the latest Mac operating system (it will also be supported by macOS 10.13 High Sierra when it is released this fall). An exact quote of the error message would be helpful.

Comment: @Phong I'll paste the the exact quote later to this thread tomorrow. Will there be a performance decrease if she is to upgrade to 10.12 due to old hardware?

Comment: It's also helpful if you provide the specs of said MBA 2012 (memory, CPU, macOS version, etc.).  Remember, we're not there to look over your shoulder.

Comment: @Allan I have updated my response. I will get her MacOS version tomorrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just doing a [quick search](https://www.bing.com/search?q=diablo%203%20system%20requirements%20mac&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN), we can find the [System requirements for Diablo III](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/34784) we see that the minimum macOS requirement is El Capitan (10.11). If you are using Yosemite (10.10) or Mavericks (10.9), this game will not work.

[image]

We also see that it's capable of running on Sierra (10.12).  You should be able to upgrade to at least El Cap with no performance issues.

To address your specific questions:

> Does Apple impose an operating system cap because her Mac is too old?

Yes.  In fact, with the release of Sierra, many [vintage](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201624) Macs were left out in the cold.

> Is it advisable to upgrade her operating system to the lastest
>   version, or would it be too much of a strain on her system resource?

It's not a requirement to upgrade unless you need to, but given your case that you wish to use a specific application (game), it's necessary.  It's always advisable to upgrade as there are lots of fixes and added features with new releases.